# Possible to lock components in Flash builder 4.5?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

Is it possible to lock components when using design mode in flash builder 4.5?

I have created a custom component in catalyst that acts as the background to the application. I need to animate this component in different states, and these are all done in catalyst.

I then imported the flash catalyst project into flash builder as a library. I was then able to drag the component into my application using design mode.

The problem is that this component has been set to stretch to fit the whole application. The code would look like:

```
<components:Background left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0"/>
```

The annoying thing is that as I drag new components in design mode onto the application, they get dragged "into" the component like so:

```
<components:Background left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:Button x="397" y="413" label="Button"/>
</components:Background>
```

This causes the background component to not show when the application executes. The correct code should be:

```
<components:Background left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0" />
<s:Button x="397" y="413" label="Button"/>
```

Is there anyway I can lock certain components in design mode so that this doesn't happen?

Comment: Obviously this wouldn't be an issue in code mode. But, I would like to drag components and position them visually in design mode.

Comment: I think that's out of the scope of the 'designer' mode.  I think Adobe is transitioning the design mode out of Flash Builder (about time IMO) and concentrating on getting that functionality into Catalyst, which I know can lock 'layers'.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the behavior you want using Skins. For instance, you could set the background on a skin. Something like: [Adding background fills and images to Spark containers](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS422719A4-7849-4921-AF39-57FF567B483B.html#WS063B0491-B7AB-4b00-A39F-E44310BCB0E0)